# Xamarin.Forms cross platform architecture

Tags: xamarin.forms, frameworks, cross-platform, prism, mvvmcross

I want to create a new cross-platform Xamarin.Forms app. But I am a bit confused about which architecture/framework to use.
There are different MVVM framework i.e MvvmCross, Prism, FreshMVVM, ReactiveUI.
So which is best to use, and what are their differences?

Comment: "which is the best" is a matter of opinion, which is considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: You might wanna read this just for a basic understanding https://xamarinhelp.com/use-xamarin-forms-mvvm-framework/

Comment: You can refer to this similar case:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100156/best-mvvm-framework every one used different framework. You could choice one of them, and test them.Notes:XForms already contains all functions of typical MVVM framework.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, Does latest Xamarin.Forms Shell features, works with this frameworks?

Comment: I test XForms MVVM framework, it support the shell

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Which MVVM framework have you tested?

Comment: Please refer to the link about MVVM.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm